# Aggregation pipeline in spring mongodb

Tags: spring, mongodb

I need to create aggregation pipleine using spring data mongo db. I am using below code to filter array of objects. It works perfectly fine

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
                match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[criteriaList.size()]))),
                project().and(new AggregationExpression() {
                    @Override
                    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
                        Document filterExpression = new Document();
                        filterExpression.put("input", "$dailyVisitorStats");
                        filterExpression.put("as", "dailyVisitorStat");
                        filterExpression.put("cond", new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$$dailyVisitorStat.weekNum", weekNum)));
                        return new Document("$filter", filterExpression);
                    }
                }).as("dailyVisitorStats")
```

but for other use case I need to add two condition. In the above example for "Cond" I need to add condition like

```
{ $and: [
       { $eq: [ "$$dailyVisitorStat.weekNum", 22 ] },
        { $gte: [ "$$dailyVisitorStat.today", ISODate("2019-06-01T00:00:00.000Z" ) ] },
        { $lte: [ "$$dailyVisitorStat.today", ISODate("2019-06-01T23:59:59.000Z" ) ] }
      ] }
  }
```

The origional MongoDb $Project stage look like below.. I am trying to write same thing in spring mongo

```
{
  "dailyVisitorStats":{
  $filter: {
     input: "$dailyVisitorStats",
     as: "dailyVisitorStat",
     cond: { $and: [
       { $eq: [ "$$dailyVisitorStat.weekNum", 22 ] },
        { $gte: [ "$$dailyVisitorStat.today", ISODate("2019-06-01T00:00:00.000Z" ) ] },
        { $lte: [ "$$dailyVisitorStat.today", ISODate("2019-06-01T23:59:59.000Z" ) ] }
      ] }
  }
}
}
```

How can I do it ???

Comment: Is your trouble resolved? Can you conclude the question by selecting an answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below snippet? I am unable to run it against a mongo instance, but it is syntactically and (hopefully) logically correct.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        match(new Criteria().andOperator(criteriaList.toArray(new Criteria[criteriaList.size()]))),
        project().and(ArrayOperators.Filter.filter("dailyVisitorStats")
                .as("dailyVisitorStat")
                .by(BooleanOperators.And.and(
                        ComparisonOperators.Eq.valueOf("dailyVisitorStat.weekNum").equalTo(weekNum),
                        ComparisonOperators.Gte.valueOf("dailyVisitorStat.today").greaterThanEqualTo(date1),
                        ComparisonOperators.Lte.valueOf("dailyVisitorStat.today").lessThanEqualTo(date2))))
            .as("dailyVisitorStats"));
```

I used the `$filter` support that is detailed here [DATAMONGO-1491](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/pull/412)